# Can I use iCloud with my devices on Windows XP?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, icloud, windows

We have two XP machines (in different cities) that up to now they have been the the hosts for syncing and backing up an iPad and iPhone via iTunes via USB.  We want to make use of iCloud, at least for backing up the iPhone and iPad.  As you know iCloud / it's control panel isn't supported on XP (without a hack to the installer).
I've got some questions about how the syncing and iCloud backup process will work in my situation.

1) Is it correct that we can enable iCloud on the iPhone and iPad (via iTunes on XP or directly on the iPhone and iPad) without the iCloud control panel being installed on XP?

2) If we use iCloud on the iPhone/iPad - and can't enable iCloud on XP - how will apps and media be synced to the XP iTunes?  Manually?

3) In the case of XP iTunes without iCloud and iPhone/iPad enabled apps, media, photos and data, is it correct that we would still benefit from iCloud automatic syncing of apps, media and data to/between the iPhone/iPad without risk of losing any media on the XP iTunes (as long as we manually sync XP iTunes with the App/iTunes Store)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Normally, it's good to keep only one question per question, as this allows other people with the same problem to find the answers more eaisly. In this case, though, the first three are all very closely related, so we can keep those. I took out the fourth and fifth, but feel free to ask them separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. [iCloud requires Windows Vista SP2 or Windows 7](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html).
2. Data will have to be synced manually, yes.
3. Yes, manually syncing iTunes will not interfere with iCloud. All devices connected to iCloud will sync automatically and update their contents in the cloud after they have been manually synced.

Comment: @mjweaver11 If this answer was helpful, you should accept it so future viewers know that.